# What are Reciprocal Roles?

Tags: financial-services-cloud

Can someone please tell me that what are the Reciprocal Roles in Financial services cloud?
Also what are their use cases?

Answer (score 2):

In FSC  when within a relationship, a reciprocal role is the role of one entity relative to another entity. For example, Proprietor role will have a reciprocal of Business, Similarly lawyer will have Client.

These role exist to model the affiliation in Financial service business.